# Prevent saving an invalid field value in Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a custom validator class, which checks the following:

> The value of the text field should have a length 5 characters.
>      The
>   first 2 chars. should be numbers.
>      The last 3 chars. should be
>   alphabets.

When setting the Standard Value of the template (eg: 12a), the indicator shows Red and the appropriate message. But after pressing `Ctrl + S`, it shows a dialog asking to save even when there is an error. After clicking OK, there is a similar dialog. Clicking on OK, saves 12a as the standard value for the field. When I refresh the content editor the value is 12a.

Is this normal Sitecore behavior. I'm expecting that the value shouldn't be saved at all, if it is invalid.

```
namespace CustomValidators
{
 [Serializable]
 public class testValidator : StandardValidator
 {
    private readonly Regex numbersRegex = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
    private readonly Regex lettersRegexnew = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]+$");

    protected override ValidatorResult Evaluate()
    {
        string value = base.GetControlValidationValue();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Length == 5)
        {
            string firstPart = value.Substring(0, 2);
            string secondPart = value.Substring(3, 3);

            if (numbersRegex.IsMatch(firstPart) && lettersRegexnew.IsMatch(secondPart))
            {
                return ValidatorResult.Valid;
            }
        }

        base.Text = "invalid value";

        return base.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.FatalError);
    }

    protected override ValidatorResult GetMaxValidatorResult()
    {
        return base.GetFailedResult(ValidatorResult.FatalError);
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "testValidator"; }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use CriticalError instead of FatalError. Could you give that a try?

Comment: No luck. I went by this article, which says, `FatalError` is the one that prevents a Save. http://www.awareweb.com/awareblog/11-11-14-sitecore-custom-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only people in certain roles, even get the option of forcing a save. Admins and I think people in the "Sitecore Developer" role.

As such, you are given the option of forcing a save through. This is normal behaviour.

Your regular editor users would not be able to save.